# Ошибка промиса в ie9

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая возвращает промис с xmlhttprequest, код компилируется с полифилами бабеля. Но вот в ie9 возникает такая вот ошибка:

Unhandled promise rejectionError: Could not complete the operation due to error c00c023f

в ответ от сервера попадает undefined, все методы xmlhttprequest не отображаются, единственное что удалось вывести в консоли, это сам конструктор :  [object XMLHttpRequest]

```js
function loadAndSortTowns() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        let url = './data/kladr.json',
            preloader = document.createElement('div'),
            req;
        preloader.className = 'input__preloader';

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        req.open('GET', url, true);
        req.responseType = 'json';
        filtrFocusOut = true;
        filterBlock.appendChild(preloader);

        console.log(req.response)
        req.addEventListener('load', function() {
            let resp = req.response;

            preloader.remove();
            filtrFocusOut = false;
            console.log(resp)
            if (resp) {
                resp.sort(function(a, b) {

                    if (a.name > b.name) {
                        return 1
                    } 
                    
                    return -1
                    
                });
                resolve(resp);
            } else {
                reoladBtn.innerHTML = 'Обновить';
                reoladBtn.className += 'reolad-btn';
                filterList.appendChild(reoladBtn);
                document.getElementById('filter-result').innerHTML = 'Что то пошло не так. Проверьте соеденинеие с интернетом и попробуйте еще раз'

            }
        });

        console.log(req.statusText)
        req.send();

    })
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте перейти на fetch и полифилл для него. IE9 достаточно старый, возможно полифилл Бабеля в нём не работает и не тестируется.

Comment: 1. Что мешает подебажить? 2. Компаратор в сортировке неверный - никогда не говорит, что объекты равны. 3. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7287706/4928642 4. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12414982/4928642

Comment: @Qwertiy все эти ответы я видел, пробовал некоторые варианты, да и особо суть не совсем понял даже с переводчиком т.к у них вроде как ошибка немножко другого рода.

Comment: @Qwertiy И не совсем понимаю зачем в сравнение они должны быть равными?
Если compareFunction(a, b) вернёт 0, сортировка оставит a и b неизменными по отношению друг к другу, но отсортирует их по отношению ко всем другим элементам. Обратите внимание: стандарт ECMAscript не гарантирует данное поведение, и ему следуют не все браузеры (например, версии Mozilla по крайней мере, до 2003 года).